# My datagridview is not displaying data

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataset

I made a datagridview which was connected to a dataset. The dataset itself has plenty of records, I've checked; but when I debug, the grid doesn't display ANYTHING, which is irritating because just a couple of days ago, this program of mine was working just fine. I haven't modified any code or file for that matter. I just took a break from opening my project for a couple of days, and when I opened it again, boom, it's not working as well as before. Here's the code that I use:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con; //sweet connection object is created in this here line
masterDataSet custMaster; //this creates an AWESOME database object
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da; //this sets up a data adapter named "da". kewl
int MaxRows = 0;
int inc = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(); //name of the sweet connection object above
    custMaster = new masterDataSet();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"; //this tells windows where to find the database DORA STYLE
    con.Open(); //this opens up the connection. I DON'T SAY?
    MessageBox.Show("Database connection has been established succesfully.");

    string sql = "SELECT * From custMaster";
    da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(custMaster, "custMaster");
    MaxRows = custMaster.Tables["custMaster"].Rows.Count;
    da.Update(custMaster, "custMaster");

    con.Close();
}
```

then, for inputting data, I have created a form with the following code. although I'm sure the error does not lie in this part, I'll type it in anyway:

```
private void newCustbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
    cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    DataRow dRow = custMaster.Tables["custMaster"].NewRow();
    dRow[1] = a_newCust.Text;
    dRow[2] = b_newCust.Text;
    dRow[3] = c_newCust.Text;
    dRow[4] = d_newCust.Text;
    dRow[5] = e_newCust.Text.ToString();
    dRow[6] = f_newCust.Text;
    dRow[7] = g_newCust.Text.ToString();
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        dRow[8] = radioButton1.Text;
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        dRow[8] = radioButton2.Text;
    }

    custMaster.Tables["custMaster"].Rows.Add(dRow);

    MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
    inc = MaxRows - 1;    

    da.Update(custMaster, "custMaster");    

    MessageBox.Show("Customer succesfully added!");
}
```

I'm pretty sure it has do with my connections. Any help would be great!

Comment: What error you are getting ... have tried putting break point and see where it's actually failing.

Comment: nevermind. i fixed it. turns out, the connection string was janked. wouldn't you know it huh?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Have you tried to put Integrated Security=SSPI?

2 - MaxRows = custMaster.Tables["custMaster"].Rows.Count; try to see how many rows ur datatable is returning?

3 - is there an error that you are getting or just empty datagrid? have you tried to run the debugger?

Comment: 1-No. but i don't see how that's the problem, i didn't put that line before either and it still worked.

2-umm, sry but, how exactly do i do that again?

3-no errors. i just run the program and the form displays nothing.

Comment: 2 - you can do that by displaying a msgbox(MaxRows)

Comment: nevermind. i fixed it. turns out, the connection string was janked. wouldn't you know it huh?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but my rep's not high enough... Anyway, so the dataset still has data and the datagridview was displaying the data a few days ago but now it isn't? If this is the case, I don't know why it would be working a few days ago and now it isn't, but maybe you could try refreshing the datagridview after you load the dataset.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem. i haven't edited any code or modified any file in the directory and stuff like that.

Comment: What happens if at the end of loading your dataset, you call the `Refresh()` function on your dataviewgrid? I'm wondering if maybe the datagridview isn't recognizing the dataset being loaded since this is occurring in a different thread than the datagridview was created. Just a theory.

Comment: nevermind. i fixed it. turns out, the connection string was janked. wouldn't you know it huh? but since we're on this topic, would the refresh command update the datagrid after i place in a new record at runtime? i mean, whenever i add a new record at runtime, it doesn't update the datagrid immediately. i have to close the run and then re-run it again to see the new record. just wondering.

Comment: Yep it should. I don't know if this is the best way to do it though, there may be ways that require less overhead, but it should work.